# error ORA-00928 en pl sql: falta la palabra clave select

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, type

Estoy utilizando %type y select into. Aun así me sigue apareciendo el error que dice que le falta un SELECT, pero no veo donde se encuentra.

```
    DECLARE
      NOMBRE EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
      APELLIDO EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
      EMAIL EMPLOYEES.EMAIL%TYPE;
      TOTAL_GANADO JOBS.MAX_SALARY%TYPE;
      CONTADOR NUMBER := 0;
      INGRESO  NUMBER;
      SALARIO EMPLOYEES.SALARY%TYPE;
      COMISION EMPLOYEES.COMMISSION_PCT%TYPE;
      REGALIA NUMBER;
    BEGIN
    SELECT FIRST_NAME ,LAST_NAME , EMAIL, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT INTO NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EMAIL, SALARIO, COMISION
    FROM EMPLOYEES 
    WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = :CODIGO ;
    
    dbms_output.put_line(NOMBRE || APELLIDO || EMAIL|| REGALIA|| TOTAL_GANADO);
    END;
```

Comment: El declare está correcto. No sé desde dónde lo llamas pero puede que te esté indicando que no acepta PLSQL y que está esperando un SELECT en vez de un DECLARE